# Limit of exponential times its truncation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

For a positive real $t$, what is the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n,t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}e^{-nt}\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac{(nt)^j}{j!}. \quad\quad\quad (\star)
$$
I expect it to be 0 as I should be the approximation error of the semi-discrete backward Euler method at $x=1$ of the advection equation $\partial_t u=-\partial_x u$, $t>0$, $u(0,x)=\mathbf 1_{\{x>0\}}$, i.e. 
$$
\partial_t u_n= -D_x^nu_n:=-n[u_n(t, x)-u_n(t, x-1/n)],\quad t>0,\quad u(0,x)=\mathbf 1_{\{x>0\}},
$$
so that

$$
u_n(t,x)-u(t,x) = e^{-tn}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor xn \rfloor}\frac{(tn)^j}{j!}\mathbf 1_{\{x-j/n>0\}} - \mathbf 1_{\{x-t>0\}}.
$$
If $(\star)=0$, is the order of convergence $O(1/n)$?

**EDIT**: Due to the suggestion, 
 one can use the following proof for convergence for fixed $0<t<1$. Using increasingness of $e^{-nz}z^n$  on $[0,n]$
\begin{align}
a(n,t)=\frac1{n!}\int_0^{nt}e^{-z}z^n\,dz= \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^{t}e^{-nz}z^n\,dz\le t \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!} e^{-nt}t^n= t \ell_n \to 0
\end{align}
as $n\to \infty$, because 
\begin{align}
 \frac{\ell_{n+1}}{\ell_n}= e^{-t}t\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^n=e^{-t}t\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n \to e^{1-t}t<1.
\end{align}
Moreover, as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n,t)\le C \sum_{n=0}^\infty \theta(t)^n<\infty$ for some $C>0$ and $\theta(t)$ close to $e^{1-t}t^2$, then for all large $n$ 
$$
a(n,t)\le C_t\frac1n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how much this could help you.
$$e^{-nt}\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac{(nt)^j}{j!}=1-\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n t)}{ \Gamma (n+1)}$$

- If $t=1$, the limit is $\frac 12$
- If $0<t<1$, the limit is $0$
- If $t>1$, the limit is $1$

Comment: Thanks, can you refer to or sketch a proof?